# Assuming you could end all life on earth in a splitsecond. Would it still be immoral to do it?

Tags: ethics

Here me out...

I recently found an interesting Youtube video of someone explaining a moral dilemma:

There is a scientist who owns a machine that can end all life on earth
within the tiniest fraction of a second. This scientist suffers from
depression and he wants to kill himself. But he knows, that if he
kills himself, everyone who cares for him will suffer.

So he thinks that maybe he should kill them too. But then everyone who cares for them will suffer as well. So the conclusion is that he can either just kill himself and cause suffering or he kills every living thing on earth and technically doesn't cause any suffering at all.

What would be the morally right thing to do and why?
Is ending Life in a splitsecond morally right or wrong? Or is it maybe a morally complete neutral act?

Comment: Maybe what this boils down to is whether life is inherently good or not. There are some interesting arguments for both sides. As a note: obviously he could just kill everything except those people and animals that have been isolated from civilization and  still cause no suffering.

Comment: @commando yes, that's probably a nice way to boil it down. But still, I think there is more to it. And yes, theoretically it wouldn't harm to keep isolated groups alive. But would it make a moral difference if he kills them anyway because lets say his machine cannot be adjusted to such an individual level?

Comment: Depends on what morality you hold to.

Comment: @NeilMeyer ok, if you hold on to an absolute morality and believe that morality exists without humans, than you have a point. But if you think that the idea of morality derives from humans, wouldn't it die with the extinction of humanity? So no matter what ideas someone has of "moral" and "immoral", if everyone ceases to exist, wouldn't it become irrelevant?

Comment: +1 for Neil Meyer, -1 for this question. At least include your presuppositions, and as it looks like, adding them answers your own question (at least partly).

Comment: @Lukas well yes, I have presuppositions. But it's a philosophical question and I don't see how you can ask such a question without having thought about it. But I don't expect my views on this to be the right ones and I still would like to hear the opinion of others about this. Well I know that Stack is not a discussion platform so maybe this question would have made more sense somewhere else. But than again, I thought philosophical questions can't be answered correctly anyway so I gave it a shot. But I'm honestly sorry if I was mistaken.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves to be downvoted simply because it does not specify a school or morality. We have plenty of ethics questions here that are open-ended in this way, and that merely invites better answers that summarize the replies of multiple major schools.

Comment: " and I still would like to hear the opinion of others about this."... I think thats the crucial point. We have a chat though, which might be better suited for such open, discussion-style question. Sorry if i sounded rude

Comment: @Lukas It's alright. But one question: do you think I should edit the question and add my own views on this or should I leave it the way it is now that it's been asked anyway?

Comment: I'm with @commando here. This is no different than the trolley problem or a similar ethical dilemma. Putting the weight on the OP to specify a school or presuppositions I think is to generate unnecessary friction.

Comment: @basilikum I think that the question is fine as is, as long as you're not framing it as a poll of people's opinions (so forget about that comment a few comments up). I think it is on the answerers to breakdown what schools of thought or what presuppositions would be relevant to this question.

Comment: Perhaps when one does kill himself, he indeed ends the lives of everything in the world that exists.

Comment: He could just not kill himself - seeing as this seems like it would cause the least suffering outside of his own head.

Comment: We don't have to get our knickers in a twist over a matter that seems easily settled by a survey; of course this'll be on a global scale.

Comment: I love these dilemmas and metaphors, they make you think. Some interesting variations: [Trolley Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trolley_problem), [Lifeboat](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifeboat_ethics). I also recommend looking at this closely related SEP article: [Doing vs. Allowing Harm](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/doing-allowing/)

Answer (score 7):

This question has a very clear intuitive answer: no, it would be horribly wrong.  The task of the philosopher is then, typically, to explain why that intuition is correct.  (Or, alternatively, to explain that it is okay, after which all the non-philosophers sigh, mutter about ivory towers, and make sure that philosophers aren't allowed to get anywhere near life-ending machines.)

Perhaps surprisingly, many moral frameworks are not very well equipped to deal with these sorts of questions in a satisfying way.  You can declare by fiat that life (or human life, or something) has intrinsic value regardless of whether there is anyone there to suffer from or enjoy it.  The categorical imperative is also not that clear here: maybe the depressed scientist would think that it would be fine if anyone else took the same actions as he was about to.  Utilitarian frameworks are not very good at balancing conflicting goals (the scientist's, to end his suffering, and most everyone else's, to keep living) since almost anything obvious you plug in as a way to combine individual value or desire yields highly counterintuitive results.

But I think when the stakes are so high we can do an end-run around most of the typical concerns.  First, it is typically considered immoral to do things to adults that they really don't want done *even if* they end up enjoying or not minding it.  (We don't extend the same courtesy to children to nearly the same degree.)  Thus, the point about the suffering is a red herring: you don't need to consider suffering to come to a conclusion.  You merely note that most people want to keep existing, and the more of them you kill, the more horribly you're violating their wishes.  You can work this into either consequentialist or deontological frameworks (choosing goal-fulfillment as a good, or via some typical formulation of the Golden Rule, for instance; not every choice will yield "the right" outcome, however).

Second, in this example there's another level at which it's the wrong thing to do: evolution selects those creatures which manage to maintain life; as an evolved creature, this scientist is doing the most un-fit thing he could possibly do, and thus from an evolutionary perspective is utterly broken.  Only those species that avoid such brokenness will survive and matter in the long run.  Many individuals of some species--including humans!--sacrifice their own lives in order to maintain the species, and our moral instincts are powerfully aligned towards this kind of survival when necessary.  Inasmuch as morality must serve evolutionary constraints, the scientist would be doing the most immoral thing possible.

Comment: I think the categorical imperative would forbid this, on the grounds that a society would not work if everyone would do this. Its the same move one has with lying and the CI. CI forbids lying, because a society in which everyone lies does not work. Not 100% sure tho, so just a comment.

Comment: @Lukas - I'm not so sure.  The CI doesn't state that society has to work; just that there are no logical contradictions.  This is great for avoiding self-serving behavior that damages the group, but the defense against group-annihilation seems pretty weak to me.  Only the "people are an end in themselves" formulation (second) seems exploitable to get out of this mess, and it is not entirely clear to me how that would work except by simply stating by fiat that this means that they must not (all) be killed.  One probably could argue it successfully; Kant himself even argued against suicide!

Comment: +1 The argument that it is wrong because people wish to live on and a violation of those wishes is considered harmful even if they wouldn't mind the outcome, is something I haven't though about. I think that's a good argument for why it still would be wrong to do something like that.

Comment: Yea, Rex, I think you're right that the "never treat people merely as a means but as an end in themselves" formulation of CI would apply here. It seems that, perhaps, you're treating them merely as a means to produce a world with no suffering (or some such end). But, of course, the other three thousand (exaggeration, for those who can't tell) formulations of CI would probably deliver conflicting answers :).

Comment: FWIW although I agree with the intuition given at the beginning of this answer, I've met people who don't, who think that killing everyone in the world instantly would not harm anyone (because dead people can't be harmed) and is therefore fine.

Comment: I think there's no reason to treat the mechanism of evolution as having moral authority, though. Evolution is not an agent with beliefs or values, it's just a bunch of things that happened. You might as well say that it is immoral to jump because gravity doesn't want you to.

Comment: @BenMillwood - There's no intrinsic moral substance or field, though.  So if you're claiming that morality doesn't actually exist in a strong sense that philosophers might like, and therefore you can't make any moral claims whatsoever, sure.  You can't.  Murder isn't wrong, either.  Nor genocide, nor stealing food from starving children in order to build a food-tower. Once you say "okay, no, we do make moral claims so let's figure out what's going on with such things and see what the answer is in this case", the answer is that this is as immoral as anything can be.

Comment: No, I'm not claiming morality doesn't exist, I'm just claiming that there's no reason to believe it happens to align with successful or unsuccessful reproductive strategies. If reproduction causes suffering in a way that isn't counterbalanced by any good, then it is immoral, regardless of whether it is evolutionarily successful.

Comment: @BenMillwood - But you are just declaring this by fiat.  Where is this morality coming from?

Comment: @RexKerr I think serious moral systems are almost universal in agreeing that suffering is bad. I moreover think that evolutionary processes don't generally act to prevent suffering, and hence "what works to ensure reproduction" and "what is moral" aren't the same (indeed, are often very different).

Comment: To be clear about a distinction here: speaking loosely, evolution teaches you to avoid suffering and equips you to do so, but does not itself push to reduce or eliminate suffering, often favouring strategies that are tortuous for nearly every creature involved as long as a greater number survive to reproductive age (see: r-selection). From a thinking, moral agent we would regard such a strategy as abhorrent.

Comment: @BenMillwood - As a thinking, moral, social, extreme-K-strategy creature of _course_ we would think of it as abhorrent unless _absolutely_ necessary.  When absolutely necessary, we not only sacrifice ourselves so our young survive, we think it is one of the most honorable and noble things possible to do.

Comment: @RexKerr but overall, would you agree that evolutionary pressure often causes extreme suffering and therefore "because the evolutionary pressure told me to do it" is not a good guide for morality?

Comment: @BenMillwood - We have to get off the ground somehow.  The universe doesn't have an intrinsic hatred of suffering.  It's just us--our instincts evolved to keep our companions safe, because as social creatures, mutual support in times of need is one of our greatest advantages.  But of course some other instincts, and some other evolved things, cause suffering.  As cognition specialists, one of our other greatest advantages is our ability to consciously adjudicate between constraints.  But fundamentally it _is_ evolutionary pressure telling us to "do it" where "it" includes "avoid suffering".

Answer (score 2):

A similar dilemma positions the scientist as a person who merely contemplates the immense suffering which exists throughout the world and considers that it might be better to end the world than to allow such suffering to continue.

In the posted example, the scientist, in comparing whether the suffering caused by his death might be worse than the ending of all human life, is elevating suffering (grief, in this case) from its role as a perfectly normal and often healthy aspect of human existence to a disaster of unbearable or near-unbearable magnitude. Regardless of which scenario is examined, the crucial aspect of both lies in the fact the scientist is ignoring ***consent***.

Let's assume for a moment that the scientist is known and loved by every person on Earth, and that their grief at his loss would be severe, akin to the sudden loss of an adored child.

Who is he to decide for anyone else the extent of any suffering they might prefer to endure in lieu of sudden death? Even in those countries where assisted suicide is legal, properly-informed consent is deemed mandatory, and even extreme grief would not be deemed as a sufficient loss of quality of life to justify assisted suicide. There is nothing in the scenario provided which suggests our usual policies relating to suicide should be ignored.

Under ethical frameworks which consider consent and bodily autonomy as vital to the functioning of a safe and just society, the scientist's 'dilemma' seems not to be a dilemma at all.

To suggest that a person might be entitled to decide to kill another person in order to somehow protect that person's wellbeing is to introduce to society an extremely irrational and damaging paradigm which would in all likelihood quickly lead to disaster and which denies people the very rights which have played a critical role in establishing the relatively stable societies we currently enjoy. In short, most people, if provided the choice, would elect not to die, but to endure grief as a difficult aspect of an ongoing life.

Comment: What a successful *raise dead* spell did you cast here ;)

Answer (score 1):

The questions boils down to whether suffering is the only factor in determining whether an action is immoral. Suppose I were to ask you if you would like me to kill you- I assume you would say no, even if I were able to guarantee that you would not suffer, and that in saying no your prime concern would be your loss of life, not the suffering your death might cause to others. Given that, it seems that the interests and preferences of others is a factor that should be taken into account when considering the moral implications of an action, not just the potential for suffering.

Answer (score 0):

We singulary have no choice whether to be born or not.Then only on ones own should one determine the end of suffering.The world ends when one dies.The world has ended for untold million yet the world goes on,the reason is simple life is something death is nothing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/54180)